# How to display some value on seekbar as default?

Tags: android, default, seekbar

I have a seekbar for example: from 0 to 10. How can I make if I want to set seekbar to 5 as default position. So in this example seekbar should start from middle.

Answer (score 48):

Use this one

```
android:progress="5"
```

Like "progress", it inherits some of it's attributes from ProgressBar. You find all the attributes at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html

Comment: I guess that I can do that by this Java code, too right?: 
seekBar.incrementProgressBy(10);
But if I want to increment progress by more then 100, it doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's your max progress value? Did you call setMax(int max)? I think you should set this to an according value.

Answer (score 25):

**To get Seekbar at the value of 5**

In the xml layout use the max value as `10`

```
  android:max="10"
```

In the java for seekbar to get at progress `5`

```
 seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 seekbar.setProgress(5);
```

thats it :)

Comment: Can I set the default progress to max using xml?

Answer (score 4):

I hope this code surely helps you.
Try this...

```
float discrete=0; 
 float start=0; 
 float end=100; 
 float start_pos=0; 
 int start_position=0; 

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    start=-10;      //you need to give starting value of SeekBar 
end=10;         //you need to give end value of SeekBar 
    start_pos=5;    //you need to give starting position value of SeekBar 

    start_position=(int) (((start_pos-start)/(end-start))*100); 
    discrete=start_pos; 
    SeekBar seek=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1); 
    seek.setProgress(start_position); 
    seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() { 

        @Override 
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "discrete = "+String.valueOf(discrete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 

        @Override 
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

        } 

        @Override 
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            // To convert it as discrete value 
            float temp=progress; 
            float dis=end-start; 
            discrete=(start+((temp/100)*dis)); 

        } 
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

default value By xml :

```
android:progress="5"
```

max value by xml

```
android:max="10"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();

seekBar_efficiency.setMax(40);

seekBar_efficiency.setProgress(35);
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        seekBar_efficiency.setProgress(20);
        timer.cancel();
    }
}, 200, 50);
```

Comment: this is type it set default at launch