# changing default start value for seekbar in android

Tags: android

the default start value for seekbar is 0. Is it possible to change that value to 10? Please explain me how to set the value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display some value on seekbar as default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8807569/how-to-display-some-value-on-seekbar-as-default)

Comment: Set progress to 10

Answer (score 0):

change from XML : to change default value of seekbar use `android:progress=""` property of `seekbar`

```
android:progress="10" 
android:max="100"
```

change from Java : to change default value of `seekbar` use `setProgress(int progress)` method

```
yourSeekbar.setProgress(10);
```

Comment: I have included  android:progress="10" . this will move the seek bar progress to 10. But I dont want to move the progress. Instead i want to start from 10.

Comment: set android:max="100" and then yourSeekbar.setProgress(10);

Comment: @archanaarumugam check updated ans as per suggestion of Akshay

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying to do the same thing only for an arc progress bar. The way that I managed to achieve my desired results was by manipulating my `.setProgress` and `.setMax` values.

If you want to start at 10 and have a max of 100, your code should follow something like this:

```
progressBar.setProgress(_______-10);
progressBar.setMax(90);
```

For setProgress it should be the number you want minus 10.. this way if you have 10, then the calculation (10-10) would give you 0 which will not move your progress bar.

For setMax.. the reason why you need to subtract 10 is because if you put 100 as your max and say the progress is (100-90).. it will give you 90 (your max)... in other words if we weren't doing any calculations for setProgress, then your setMax should remain the same, but since we did a calculation for setProgress, you have to do the same calculation for your set max.

Answer (score 0):

You can set it via xml, i dont know if you still need this but here is the answer:

`android:min="10000" android:max="100000" android:progress="5000"`

Answer (score 0):

With the unit your seekBar is using, use two equal signs to make a default value.

In a previous case I had before, I used the following:

```
paintBrush.strokeWidth == 8f
```

'paintBrush', was the pen I was using in my drawing app, and strokeWidth, refers to how thick the pen is. I used two 'equal signs', meaning that this value can be changed, then followed it with the default value (thickness of the pen).

I am also new to android studio, but I do this. Hope it helps!!
*Sorry answer is late.